# Site não se conecta à base de dados depois de publicado

Tags: microsoft-azure

Publiquei uma aplicação WEB (desenvolvida em `C#`) no Azure que recorre a uma base de dados, acontece que quando tento corre-la através do domínio fornecido pelo Azure, dá-me o seguinte erro:

> "Server Error in '/' Application."
>   "Login failed for user '{meu nome}'".

Pelo que percebi o erro tem que ver com o acesso aos dados.

Quando testo a conexão no Visual Studio, antes de fazer a publicação, não me dá erro nenhum. Também consigo aceder ao servidor através do Server Object Explorer sem qualquer problema. Já pesquisei bastante e tentei várias coisas, mas parece que nada resulta.

Em meu projeto utilizo *Entity Framework Code First Migrations*.

Comment: Essa base está no servidor do azure ou está local na sua máquina? Tentou publicar sua aplicação no IIS local para testar.

Comment: A base de dados esta nos servidores do azure. Não, publiquei no azure sem testar no IIS

Comment: O seu problema e de permissão de usuário, você não tem permissão de acesso com esse usuário do servidor que está acessado

Comment: Esse link talvez te ajude a configurar a permissão do usuário. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297944/server-error-in-application-login-failed-for-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve configurar seu banco de dados para ser acessado a partir de App Services - no seu caso, um WebApp.

1. Acesse as regras de firewall do seu banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. De a permissão de acesso por Azure Services.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que com isso deva resolver o problema.

Veja aqui para saber mais sobre [criar e gerenciar regras de firewall no Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#creating-and-managing-firewall-rules).